# Widget blogger doesn't appear in mobile view

Tags: html, xml, facebook, widget, blogger

I tried to add widget on my blogger template, and I did exactly what it's supposed to do, the widget is appear in my website, but why it doesn't appear in mobile view?

Actually, I want to add Facebook like box widget. I did all what Facebook tells me:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script>(function(d, s, id) { 
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
if (d.getElementById(id)) return; 
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; 
js.src = &quot;//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;appId=[MyAppId]&amp;version=v2.0&quot;;
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I also placed the code for the plugin widget where it will appear on my page:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="[MyFbPageUrl]" data-width="250" data-height="200" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="false"></div>
```

but really the widget doesn't appear when I checked my blog on my mobile device. Should I add some additional codes to make them appear, I will be grateful for the help.

*By the way, I made the template from scratch by myself.

Answer (score 1):

I read your post and according to you it appears in desktop but not in mobile view. You can make it appear in just a second by following below steps:

1. Go to blogger and navigate to layout.
2. Edit the widget which contains above code.
3. Find the id of the widget...you can find id of widget in the link of the opened window.
4. After finding it go to template and edit it.
5. Click on jump to widget... and choose the id which you found in step 3.
6. You will see this line when you jump to the widget:

   b:widget id='HTML9' locked='false' title='' type='HTML'
7. Just add this mobile='yes' the overall line should be like below

   b:widget id='HTML9' locked='false' title='' **mobile='yes'** type='HTML'
8. Save your template and you are done... now check your blog in your phone.

If the widget still fails to appear then follow below link.

Source link: http://101helper.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-show-widget-in-mobile-view-in.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Fahim. Used your instructions to FINALLY show up Featured post in mobile. It works (at least with Custome mobile theme).